# built-in method for a nice HashSet representation as a string?

Tags: c#, hashset

Does a built-in method exist to convert a HashSet object into a string which is nicely readable? The `ToString` method just gives me the class name.

I am looking for something like this:

```
HashSet<int> h = new HashSet<int>();
h.Add(0);
h.Add(1);
h.ToNiceString(); // [0, 1]
```

Comment: Don't forget HashSets are not ordered so you may want to include a `OrderBy` on any of the solutions given if you want the text in the list to be in the same order every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.Join(", ", anyCollection)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
string nice = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", h));
```

If you want to use a generic extension

```
string nice = h.ToNiceString();

public static string ToNiceString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
{
    return string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", seq)); 
}
```

Comment: It could be better if you use this in a `.ToNiceString()` method `:)`